# No sé de donde sale este margen izquierdo en menú de navegación

Tags: html, css, flexbox, menu

Tengo el siguiente código de un menú de navegación sencillo

```css
<style>
        body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        nav{
            background-color: chocolate;
            

        }
        nav ul{
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            
            
        }
        nav ul li{
            
            padding: 16px;
            
        }
        nav ul li a{
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }
        nav ul li:hover{
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Acerca de</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
```

Mi pregunta es de donde sale y como puedo quitar el margen izquierdo que aparece antes de Inicio. He repasado el código un montón de veces y no le encuentro la solución ni tampoco saber por qué ocurre. En teoría el body tiene un margin y un padding de 0, he probado a ponerle una anchura de width 100% por si solucionaba algo a los li y nada, al ul y nada, al header nav y nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos los navegadores traen **clases css preestablecidas** para las etiquetas html, puedes eliminar las clases para tu ul con

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Aunque lo ideal, es que uses css reset para tu proyecto, de esta forma evitas estos inconvenientes en diferentes partes de tu proyecto. un ejemplo sería...

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Esto resetearía los márgenes y paddings de todas tus etiquetas.
Otra opción sería usar un archivo reset de los que hay en la red, por ejemplo:
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Los archivos css reset son parte de cualquier proyecto, lee un poco y quédate con el que mas se adapte a tus proyectos.

Comment: Solucionado gracias! Aunque sigo sin comprenderlo, si estoy trabajando en el body, no se supone que body{ margin: 0 ; padding: 0;} Hace lo mismo que *{margin:0; padding:0} ?

Comment: Tu problema no estaba en el body, sino en el ul, este también trae tus propiedades css preestablecidas, al igual que los "p", "h1", "h2", etc, de alli la necesidad de un reset general.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de ver lo que sucede y de donde está tomando los estilos la página es usando el inspector del navegador, ya sea que uses Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

En este caso, hice justamente eso, y existe un padding que se añade al elemento `ul`. Si deseas cambiarlo puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
}
```

O lo ajustas según veas conveniente.

Comment: Solucionado gracias!